# If $\mathrm{rank}(T) = \dim(W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and $T$ is a linear transformation such that $T:V\longrightarrow W$. Furthermore, if $T$ is onto then $\mathrm{rank}(T) = \dim(W)$ right? The range is on the entire codomain then. This is not a homework question I'm reviewing. I know it sounds stupid but I want to make sure I'm not missing something. Shouldn't this be the definition of onto? It's funny because this statement isn't mentioned anywhere in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathrm{rk}(T) = \dim(\mathrm{Im}(T))$ by definition, so if $T$ is surjective, $\dim(W) = \dim(\mathrm{Im}(T))$. A surjective function is a function whose image is equal to its codomain. In fact, that's the very definition of being onto.

Comment: Thanks. It's in the appendix. :P